# My program is for the most part done, but I can't get the statements to print in lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation

My code so far:

```
untranslated = open('english.txt','r')
vowels = ('a','e','i','o','u')
newWords = []

for lines in untranslated:
    words = lines.split()
    for word in words:
        if word[0] in vowels:
            word = word + 'yay'
        else:
            while word[0] not in vowels:
                word = word[1:] + word[0]
            word = word + 'ay'
        print(word)
```

Contents of the english.txt file:

```
these are lines
meant to be translated
to piglatin
```

So far I have translated all of the words but my problem is that it's not returning to the same lines as they were inputed.

I want the end result to look like:

```
esethay areyay ineslay
eantmay otay ebay anslatedtray
otay iglatinpay
```

How would I go about doing this?

What i'm getting is:

```
esethay
areyay
ineslay
eantmay
otay
ebay
anslatedtray
otay
iglatinpay
```

Comment: You want that to happen, and what is the result you're having?

Comment: @Rubens Just edited my post with what my results are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend making a list first, then printing the elements.

```
for lines in untranslated:
    latin = []
    words = lines.split()
    for word in words:
        if word[0] in vowels:
            word = word + 'yay'
        else:
            while word[0] not in vowels:
                word = word[1:] + word[0]
            word = word + 'ay'
        latin.append(word)
    print(' '.join(latin))
```

This will make a new list every line. The resulting words are appended to the list, then we join the words with a `' '` and print them.

Comment: That sounds about right! I was thinking about trying something like this but I assumed I was wrong. thanks for the help.

Comment: You even already had the `newWords = []` container ready, you just weren't using it :P

Answer (score 0):

You're printing one word per line. If you want to print one sentence per line, you could use `join`:

```
pl_words = []

for word in words:
   ...
   pl_words.append(word)

print(' '.join(pl_words))
```

Or the `end` keyword argument to `print`:

```
    print(word, end=' ')

print()  # To make a new line
```

---

I would do it with regex, though:

```
import re

words = '''
    these are lines
    meant to be translated
    to piglatin
'''

vowels = 'aeiou'

def pig_latinize(word):
    if word[0] in vowels:
        return word + 'yay'

    while word[0] not in vowels:
        word = word[1:] + word[0]

    return word + 'ay'

def replacer(match):
    return pig_latinize(match.group())

print(re.sub(r'(\w+)', replacer, words))
```